# SyntaxError: EOL while scanning string literal — Why are my quotation marks being ignored?

Tags: python, python-2.7, syntax

I am trying to follow 'How to Learn Python the Hard way' and am running into issues at a very early stage. When I try to run my first program 'hello world', I get a syntax error.

Error message:

```
File "ex1.py", line 1

print "Hello World!
                   ^
SyntaxError: EOL while scanning string literal
```

The code is written in my text file:

```
print "Hello World!"
print "Hello Again"
```

I've saved the file as a `.py`. I've rewritten the code about five times. I've even copy and pasted the authors code and I still get the same error. Judging from the error message, it seems as though I haven't put a quotation mark after 'World!'. However, there is a quotation there.

I also noticed that the error was printing the first quotation mark — just before the H of hello. I think these issues must be related. Somehow I think the parser is ignoring my quotation marks.

Comment: I don't see a quotation in the code that you posted.

Comment: The exact code, as written in atom (the text editor I use) is as follows — print "Hello World!"
// print "Hello Again"
// print "I like typing this."
// print "This is fun."
// print 'Yay! Printing.'
// print "I'd much rather you 'not'."
// print 'I "said" do not touch this.'

Comment: It would be better to put the exact code in the question - you should be able to edit it. That way you can preserve the formatting. To confirm: The arrow below the line points to the exclamation mark? What happens if you delete the exclamation mark?

Comment: If you do a `cat ex1.py` on the command line, do you see the correct content?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what fixed it, but I ended up deleting the file and host folder via the terminal with "rm -R", restarting my computer, and creating a new folder to work from through atom. I then followed the same steps, the same way, and it ran. Thanks for your patience guys. If you're stuck on this, just try deleting everything involved and restarting your computer.

Answer (score 0):

your missing the ending double qoutes `print "Hello World!"`

UPDATE:
It's working fine. 
Save that in atom. With print on every line "Not one line". 
ex: save it to "test.py" without qoutes. 
And run `python test.py`

```
print "Hello World!" 
print "Hello Again" 
print "I like typing this." 
print "This is fun." 
print 'Yay! Printing.' 
print "I'd much rather you 'not'." 
print 'I "said" do not touch this.'
```

No spaces before the print statement.

Comment: I have it written that way in my text file. My question is why my text file quotations aren't carrying over into my command line.

Comment: @EnzoCnop: No, your question is "Why do I get a `SyntaxError: EOL while scanning string literal`". Maybe you edit a different file than you're running.

Comment: These questions are one in the same. I have the quotations around "Hello World!" written as recommended in my text file, but the error tells me I don't have those quotations. I'm trying to figure out why I'm getting this error when the quotations are correctly placed in the text file.

Answer (score 0):

Check the end quote character is really an ascii quote character ". Check the exclamation mark really is an ascii exclamation mark. Delete the entire line and retype it if required. It is possible you used special unicode characters instead of the ASCII characters.

However when I try this:

```
print "dddddd”
```

I get:

```
$ python abc
  File "abc", line 1
SyntaxError: Non-ASCII character '\xe2' in file abc on line 1, but no encoding declared; see http://python.org/dev/peps/pep-0263/ for details
```

If I declare the UTF-8 character set however (something you have not indicated you have done):

```
-*- coding: utf-8 -*-
print "dddddd”
```

Then I get a similar error (although a bit different):

```
  File "abc", line 2
    print "dddddd”
                   ^
SyntaxError: EOL while scanning string literal
```

Comment: Atom indicates I'm in UTF-8. Although this is useful, and good to know going forward. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using parentheses with the 'print' statement? Like this:

```
print('Hello')
```

BR

Comment: Probably good for Python 3 compatibility, but this question was about Python 2.7. Python 2.7 doesn't require parentheses for the print statement. Although it might be helpful to see if the error changes...